Changing price of specific in app purchase item in andorid and apple store
Lets imagine we have android and IOS applications on stores. We have button that buys some shield for our character. When we click button, we get screen with 3 bundle options:
red shield - 1$
silver shield - 2$
gold shield - 3$
We designed this bundle screen.
First question I want to ask is: Is it possible to constantly change in app purchase prices in small amounts of time. Imagine we want to change the price every 1 week and update it to bigger price. Do google or apple make problems about this?
second question is: Since I read that we change price in google play and that it needs time for this change to propagate, how do we change our bundle in the app?
If we for example have bundle (nicely designed screen) that shows these prices, if we update them, we also need to update the prices in the app.
Even if we do it configurable via backend for example, how can we synchronize with google/apple and moment they propagate their change?
I see situations where we updated price on our native Buy screen, but google has not yet released update of prices on their side and vice versa.
How do we tackle this problem, am I missing something? (this is situation where we want custom made screen for buying)
Thanks.

You cannot store the price of a purchase in your code or on your server.  You need to fetch the current price from the relevant store at run time.
If you have the price in your code, then you need an app update to show a different price, and people who have not updated will see an incorrect price.
If you fetch the prices from your server at run time, you would still have problems because, as you point out, you cannot know exactly when a price change will occur on the store.
There is also the complexity of dealing with prices in different currencies and in different countries and knowing which of those currencies apply.
The stores will also periodically adjust the prices in different countries without your input in order to adjust for tax changes or exchange rate variations.
For these reasons you need to fetch the current price from the store and show that in your user interface.
On iOS you can use the displayPrice property of the Product.  This price is automatically localised and adjusted based on the user's store country and currency.
Similarly, for Google Play Store, you can use the getFormattedPrice function of the one time purchase offer details that you get from the ProductDetails object.
If you use these values then your store interface will automatically adapt to the user's currency symbol, currency and the price they will be charged.

ok but if the stores will update price without my input, than this shield can be instead od 3$ it can be 3.11$? That looks like ugly and unrounded price... I plan to have it on my UI (as you said fetch price at the cold start of the app). It would look ugly to show unrounded price..
About complexity of dealing with prices in different courencies -> if I for example set on google store that price is 3$, does google play take care of the countries where they use other currency or? Can I always display price 3 $ in my app for every country in the world? I care only about nice look and UI.

You have to get the price from the store. I only have experience with Apple, but they always adjust the price so that it is .0 or .99 depending on the country.  Apple and Google will adjust the amount charged based on the currency of the user's store.  And you don't know what that is.  For example, one of my apps that is AUD$9.99 is 17900 Tanzanian Shillings and 149000 Vietnamese Dong.  If I just showed $9.99 in my app it would be of no use to people in those countries.  If you use the properties  in my answer then you will always display the right price for the user in their currency

Also, with Apple, you can only pick specific price points and $3 isn't one of them.  You can pick $2.99 or $3.99

so you want to tell me that in my app IN APP PURCHASES are forced to  have weird prices because of this things. That is really unpleasant info for me I have to admit. And it is bad for UX/UI of user to see for example 2.99€ on the button to buy. Looks like some cheap buy store ideology...

Actually, for IAPs you can select $3. It is just app purchases that are more limited, but you still need to get the price from the store API because you can't know what the user will be charged in their country/currency

so if I understood well, we can set prices for In app pruchases (like buying shield) to rounded values (2$ after that 3$, 4$...). And every time we update price in app, button for buying will show exactly these values. So user will be shown in app 3$. But after that, user will be taken to the apple/google pay system and there the price will be shown for example in krunas (213kruna, or little bit less/more dollars 3.08$ instead of 3$ that is shown in my app?)? Is that what you want to say. If that is the case than it is not problem because UX and UI will not be damaged inside the app

No, if you use the properties from my answer the user will be shown the amount they will be charged, in the currency in which they will pay directly in your app. So if you have selected US$3 as your base price then the Australian price would be AUD$5 by default (you can set country specific prices if you want). It makes no sense to show me $3 in your app when I will pay $5; displayPrice will show "$5" because StoreKit knows that my store account is Australian. You don't need to have the prices in your app and you can't. You just have the prices against your IAPs in the stores.

understood, we can not affect this. If the user is for example in australia, he might be shown price for shield AUD4.58$. We get this value from the "store" and we show it. Ok thanks a lot for clarification and for your time, I appreciate it!

They would never see a value of $4.58. The current Apple equivalent of a US$3 is AUD$5; this is about AUD$4.50 because of the exchange rate and 10% sales tax, brings it to $4.95 but Apple will round it to $5.  If it came out at $5.05 then they would round it down to $5. The values will be adjusted peridically if there have been big movements in exchange rate.

great that is even better info!

pls one more question. If I have to make prices that drop with the amount user buys. For example 5 armor = 5$, 10armor = 8$, fulfill armor = dynamic price, we would firstly see how much more armor user needs to fulfill it (lets say 7 armor) and than use some formula which we use for calculating price. Is this possilble to set up on google and apple? I was thinkinh about defining value for 1 item and than putting fromula that for example lowers price for every another item for 3%.

You can't compute prices dynamically. Prices need to be set for the particular product. This is for security reasons. If the app could determine a price itself then an attacker could potentially manipulate the app to purchase things for 0.  You can have different IAP products for the same "item" in your app and then your app decides which  product to purchase. So you could have "armour.5.normal" and "armour.5.discount" with two different prices but both give you five armour in your app.

armor can go to 15 max. When user buys IAP option "fill armor to max", He can have for example 3 armor at that moment (so he will buy 12 more) or 7 armor (so he will buy 8 more). Price of 1 armor is 1$, but as we go higher, the price drops. So 8 armor will be something like 6$. If I understood you well, I would define 15 prices for this item? every price will represent situation where user buys 1,2,3..,15 armors. Than I would dinamicaly see at the moment when user clicks "buy" how much armor he has. And decide which price to use (if he has 3, I would give him price of 12)?

For iOS with consumable type IAP you can specify the quantity that a user is purchasing, so you could have a single, discounted, item and then submit a purchase transaction for 12 or 8 as required. Again, though, the store will do the math and show the price. You can't control that. Be careful about making things too complicated. Monetisation is a careful balance between getting people to purchase and driving them crazy with complications and fees.

ok understood. Thanks a lot man you are awesome <3
